# asp net core 3.1 angular windows authentication required username and password

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

i'm using asp net core 3.1 with angular i want to combine windows authentication and JWT for canactivate in angular while routing and authorize the controller but always required windows username and password while i pass the token from interceptor to the controller

```
request.clone({ headers: request.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + user.token) });
```

my launchSettings.json change to below

```
"windowsAuthentication": true,
"anonymousAuthentication": false,
```

add below code to the startup ConfigureServices

```
var appSettingsSection = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
            services.Configure<AppSettings>(appSettingsSection);

            // configure jwt authentication
            var appSettings = appSettingsSection.Get<AppSettings>();
            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(appSettings.Secret);
            services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(x =>
            {
                x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                x.SaveToken = true;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };
            });
```

add below code to the startup Configure

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hardly combine windows and jwt token authentication if you are hosting your application on IIS. Both JWT and Windows authentication utilize the Authorization header in Http Request Header, but IIS takes it over first, when your request is a JWT request, the Authorization header you sent is some like this

```
Authorization: Bearer {jwtcontent}
```

Then iis windows authentication module takes over your request and found it can not recognize your Authorization header, so it responses to your request with 401 and a Authorization header like this(Negotiate)

```
Authorization: Negotiate YIIg8gYGKwY[...]hdN7Z6yDNBuU=
```

or (for NTLM)

```
Authorization: NTLM TlRMTVN[...]ADw==
```

Your browser receives this response and found server is looking for a windows credential so it pops up a windows asking you to type in your username and pwd

All of these are handled by IIS and Browser, it does not even goes to your application code.

Comment: there is any project in github ?

Comment: What do you mean by any project? A project combine windows auth and jwt bearer auth? We can use kersel to host our website and in every controller, specify the [Authorize(scheme={your auth scheme}] attribute to force your action to use both jwt and windows. See this document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-3.1#use-multiple-authentication-schemes

Comment: if there is any completed project it was greate